# Is it possible to edit a treetable in Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

The following treeTable is needed to be edited so as to enable data insertion from the JSF to Backing Bean classes.

```html
<p:treeTable id="labBillTree" value="#{labBillMB.root}" var="document" scrollable="true">       
    <p:column headerText="Item Code" width="140" sortBy="#{document.code}"
         filterBy="#{document.code}" filterMatchMode="contains">
          <h:outputText value="#{document.code}" />
    </p:column>
</p:treeTable>
```

The above code will anyhow display the list of ItemCode in normal hierarchical tree format. How can we come across this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to edit the code, simply replace

```
<h:outputText value="#{document.code}" />
```

by

```
<p:inputText value="#{document.code}" />
```

Comment: isn't there any button like in row edit to initiate an action in back end to save new text input into Database after input has been changed in inputText box.